# Select columns from a highly nested data

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, avro

For the dataframe below, which was generated from an avro file, I'm trying to get the column names as a list or other format so that I can use it in a select statement. `node1` and `node2` have the same elements. For example I understand that we could do `df.select(col('data.node1.name'))`, but I'm not sure

1. how to select all columns at once without hardcode all the column names, and
2. how to handle the nested part. I think to make it readable, the `productvalues` and `porders` should be selected into separate individual dataframes/tables?

Input schema:

```
root
  |-- metadata: struct
  |...
  |-- data :struct 
  |    |--node1 : struct
  |    |   |--name : string
  |    |   |--productlist: array
  |    |        |--element : struct
       |              |--productvalues: array
       |                   |--element : struct
       |                         |-- pname:string
       |                         |-- porders:array
       |                                |--element : struct
       |                                      |-- ordernum: int
       |                                      |-- field: string
       |--node2 : struct
  |        |--name : string
  |        |--productlist: array
  |             |--element : struct
                      |--productvalues: array
                          |--element : struct
                                 |-- pname:string
                                 |-- porders:array
                                        |--element : struct
                                              |-- ordernum: int
                                              |-- field: string
```

Comment: since you have plenty of `array` structure in your schema, how would you plan of selecting that with your select statement? would that be a **very very long and cryptic** query like `productlist[12]productvalues[7]porders[0].ordernum`?

Comment: @pltc that's why I'm wondering how to handle the nested part, e.g. if array should be separated to another two tables and select only the outer level in the select statement.

Comment: so what is precisely the desired results here? I don't think that there is an easy way for simplifying your select statement for such structure hence you will need first to transform your data, i.e explode arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following way, you will not need to hardcode all the struct fields. But you will need to provide a list of those columns/fields which have the type of *array of struct*. You have 3 of such fields, we will add one more column, so in total it will be 4.

First of all, the dataframe, similar to yours:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(
        ('a', 'b'),
        (
            (
                'name_1',
                [
                    ([
                        (
                            'pname_111',
                            [
                                (1111, 'field_1111'),
                                (1112, 'field_1112')
                            ]
                        ),
                        (
                            'pname_112',
                            [
                                (1121, 'field_1121'),
                                (1122, 'field_1122')
                            ]
                        )
                    ],),
                    ([
                        (
                            'pname_121',
                            [
                                (1211, 'field_1211'),
                                (1212, 'field_1212')
                            ]
                        ),
                        (
                            'pname_122',
                            [
                                (1221, 'field_1221'),
                                (1222, 'field_1222')
                            ]
                        )
                    ],)
                ]
            ),
            (
                'name_2',
                [
                    ([
                        (
                            'pname_211',
                            [
                                (2111, 'field_2111'),
                                (2112, 'field_2112')
                            ]
                        ),
                        (
                            'pname_212',
                            [
                                (2121, 'field_2121'),
                                (2122, 'field_2122')
                            ]
                        )
                    ],),
                    ([
                        (
                            'pname_221',
                            [
                                (2211, 'field_2211'),
                                (2212, 'field_2212')
                            ]
                        ),
                        (
                            'pname_222',
                            [
                                (2221, 'field_2221'),
                                (2222, 'field_2222')
                            ]
                        )
                    ],)
                ]
            )
        ),
    )],
    'metadata:struct<fld1:string,fld2:string>, data:struct<node1:struct<name:string, productlist:array<struct<productvalues:array<struct<pname:string, porders:array<struct<ordernum:int, field:string>>>>>>>, node2:struct<name:string, productlist:array<struct<productvalues:array<struct<pname:string, porders:array<struct<ordernum:int, field:string>>>>>>>>'
)
```

```py
# df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- metadata: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- fld1: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- fld2: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- node1: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- productlist: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |    |    |-- productvalues: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- pname: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- porders: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- ordernum: integer (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- field: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- node2: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- productlist: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |    |    |-- productvalues: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- pname: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- porders: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- ordernum: integer (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- field: string (nullable = true)
```

**The answer**

- Spark 3.1+

  ```py
  nodes = df.select("data.*").columns
  for n in nodes:
      df = df.withColumn("data", F.col("data").withField(n, F.struct(F.lit(n).alias("node"), f"data.{n}.*")))
  df = df.withColumn("data", F.array("data.*"))

  for arr_of_struct in ["data", "productlist", "productvalues", "porders"]:
      df = df.select(
          *[c for c in df.columns if c != arr_of_struct],
          F.expr(f"inline({arr_of_struct})")
      )
  ```
- Lower Spark versions:

  ```py
  nodes = df.select("data.*").columns
  for n in nodes:
      df = df.withColumn(
          "data",
          F.struct(
              F.struct(F.lit(n).alias("node"), f"data.{n}.*").alias(n),
              *[f"data.{c}" for c in df.select("data.*").columns if c != n]
          )
      )
  df = df.withColumn("data", F.array("data.*"))

  for arr_of_struct in ["data", "productlist", "productvalues", "porders"]:
      df = df.select(
          *[c for c in df.columns if c != arr_of_struct],
          F.expr(f"inline({arr_of_struct})")
      )
  ```

Results:

```py
df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- metadata: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- fld1: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- fld2: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- node: string (nullable = false)
#  |-- name: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- pname: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- ordernum: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- field: string (nullable = true)

df.show()
# +--------+-----+------+---------+--------+----------+
# |metadata| node|  name|    pname|ordernum|     field|
# +--------+-----+------+---------+--------+----------+
# |  {a, b}|node1|name_1|pname_111|    1111|field_1111|
# |  {a, b}|node1|name_1|pname_111|    1112|field_1112|
# |  {a, b}|node1|name_1|pname_112|    1121|field_1121|
# |  {a, b}|node1|name_1|pname_112|    1122|field_1122|
# |  {a, b}|node1|name_1|pname_121|    1211|field_1211|
# |  {a, b}|node1|name_1|pname_121|    1212|field_1212|
# |  {a, b}|node1|name_1|pname_122|    1221|field_1221|
# |  {a, b}|node1|name_1|pname_122|    1222|field_1222|
# |  {a, b}|node2|name_2|pname_211|    2111|field_2111|
# |  {a, b}|node2|name_2|pname_211|    2112|field_2112|
# |  {a, b}|node2|name_2|pname_212|    2121|field_2121|
# |  {a, b}|node2|name_2|pname_212|    2122|field_2122|
# |  {a, b}|node2|name_2|pname_221|    2211|field_2211|
# |  {a, b}|node2|name_2|pname_221|    2212|field_2212|
# |  {a, b}|node2|name_2|pname_222|    2221|field_2221|
# |  {a, b}|node2|name_2|pname_222|    2222|field_2222|
# +--------+-----+------+---------+--------+----------+
```

Explanation

```py
nodes = df.select("data.*").columns
for n in nodes:
    df = df.withColumn("data", F.col("data").withField(n, F.struct(F.lit(n).alias("node"), f"data.{n}.*")))
```

Using the above, I decided to save the node title in case you need it.
It first gets a list of nodes from "data" column fields. Using the list, the `for` loop creates one more field inside every node struct for the title of the node.

```py
df = df.withColumn("data", F.array("data.*"))
```

The above converts the "data" column type from struct to array so that in the next step we could easily explode it into columns.

```py
for arr_of_struct in ["data", "productlist", "productvalues", "porders"]:
    df = df.select(
        *[c for c in df.columns if c != arr_of_struct],
        F.expr(f"inline({arr_of_struct})")
    )
```

In the above, the main line is `F.expr(f"inline({arr_of_struct})")`. It must be used inside a loop, because it's a generator and you cannot nest them together in Spark. [**`inline`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#inline) explodes *arrays of structs* into columns. At this step you have 4 of [array of struct], so 4 `inline` expressions will be created.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of collecting all data into a table, I would recommend you making more tables for each list. In order to get values from list you can use the `explode` function.For instance, for making `productlist` table:

```py
productlist = df.select(col('data.node1.name').alias("name"), explode(col('data.node1.productlist'))).alias("first_explode"))
```

In the next step, you can use the `df` of `productlist` , and run the below sector:

```py
productValue=df.select(col('productlist.name'),col('productlist.node1.first_explode.element'),explode(col('productlist.node1.first_explode.productvalues')).alias("second_explode"))
```

and so on. You can also get some help from the [this](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-explode-array-and-map-columns-to-rows/) link as well.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is not a perfect answer for you, but I hope it might give you some ideas to solve your problem. I know you said you don't want to hardcode your column names but I'm unable to handle that part at this moment.

First thing first, I created this sample JSON for testing

```
{
    "metadata": {},
    "data": {
        "node1": {
            "name": "Node001",
            "productlist": [
                {
                    "productvalues": [
                        {
                            "pname": "Node001-P001",
                            "porders": [
                                {"ordernum":  1, "field": "Node001-P001-001"},
                                {"ordernum":  2, "field": "Node001-P001-002"}
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "pname": "Node001-P002",
                            "porders": [
                                {"ordernum":  3, "field": "Node001-P002-003"},
                                {"ordernum":  4, "field": "Node001-P002-004"},
                                {"ordernum":  5, "field": "Node001-P002-005"},
                                {"ordernum":  6, "field": "Node001-P002-006"}
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "pname": "Node001-P003",
                            "porders": [
                                {"ordernum":  7, "field": "Node001-P003-007"}
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "productvalues": [
                        {
                            "pname": "Node001-P004",
                            "porders": [
                                {"ordernum":  8, "field": "Node001-P004-008"},
                                {"ordernum":  9, "field": "Node001-P004-009"},
                                {"ordernum": 10, "field": "Node001-P004-010"}
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "pname": "Node001-P005",
                            "porders": [
                                
                                {"ordernum": 11, "field": "Node001-P005-011"},
                                {"ordernum": 12, "field": "Node001-P005-012"},
                                {"ordernum": 13, "field": "Node001-P005-013"}
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "node2": {
            "name": "Node002",
            "productlist": [
                {
                    "productvalues": [
                        {
                            "pname": "Node002-P001",
                            "porders": [
                                {"ordernum": 14, "field": "Node002-P001-014"}
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "pname": "Node002-P002",
                            "porders": [
                                {"ordernum": 15, "field": "Node002-P002-015"}
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "pname": "Node002-P003",
                            "porders": [
                                {"ordernum": 16, "field": "Node002-P003-016"}
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "productvalues": [
                        {
                            "pname": "Node002-P004",
                            "porders": [
                                {"ordernum": 17, "field": "Node002-P004-017"}
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "pname": "Node002-P005",
                            "porders": [
                                
                                {"ordernum": 18, "field": "Node002-P005-018"}
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this is a "dict-like" column that you need to use for later

```
cols_dict = [
    {
        'col': ['data.node1.name'],
        'exp': ['data.node1.productlist'],
    },
    {
        'exp': ['productlist.productvalues'],
    },
    {
        'col': ['productvalues.pname'],
        'exp': ['productvalues.porders'],
    },
    {
        'col': ['porders.ordernum', 'porders.field']
    }
]
```

And finally, loop through this dict and add some transformation to get your final result

```
dfx = df
select_col = []
for i in cols_dict:
    select_col = [c.split('.')[-1] for c in select_col]
    if i.get('col'):
        select_col += i['col']
    
    select_exp = []
    if i.get('exp'):
        select_exp += i['exp']

    dfx = dfx.select([F.col(c) for c in select_col] + [F.explode(c).alias(c.split('.')[-1]) for c in select_exp])

+-------+------------+--------+----------------+
|   name|       pname|ordernum|           field|
+-------+------------+--------+----------------+
|Node001|Node001-P001|       1|Node001-P001-001|
|Node001|Node001-P001|       2|Node001-P001-002|
|Node001|Node001-P002|       3|Node001-P002-003|
|Node001|Node001-P002|       4|Node001-P002-004|
|Node001|Node001-P002|       5|Node001-P002-005|
|Node001|Node001-P002|       6|Node001-P002-006|
|Node001|Node001-P003|       7|Node001-P003-007|
|Node001|Node001-P004|       8|Node001-P004-008|
|Node001|Node001-P004|       9|Node001-P004-009|
|Node001|Node001-P004|      10|Node001-P004-010|
|Node001|Node001-P005|      11|Node001-P005-011|
|Node001|Node001-P005|      12|Node001-P005-012|
|Node001|Node001-P005|      13|Node001-P005-013|
+-------+------------+--------+----------------+
```